# Running GNU Screen on Raspbian with vertival split spilling content

Tags: zsh, raspberry-pi, gnu-screen, raspbian

I am running Screen on a Raspberry Pi. My shell on the Pi is ZSH with OH-MY-ZSH. I have connected to the Pi via SSH from a Mac. When I run certain commands like HTOP or Vim the output spills over to the second screen. You can see it in the screenshot below. How do I stop the content of one window spilling in to the next?

[image: GNU Screen Spilling on to second vertical split.]